# Docker compose: working directory needs to be an absolute path

Tags: docker-compose, scrapyd

I have this folder structure:

```
services/
        web/
           project/
                  api/
                     scrapy.cfg
```

And this is how I build my container which needs `scrapy.cfg`:

```
  web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'    
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    depends_on:  
      - web-db
      - redis

  scrapyrt:
    image: vimagick/scrapyd:py3
    command: scrapyrt -i 0.0.0.0 -p 9080
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9080:9080'
    volumes:
      - ./services/web:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - web
```

However it throws the following error:

```
ERROR: for scrapyrt  Cannot create container for service scrapyrt: the working directory './services/web/project/api' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How do I set this absolute path to scrapy.cfg? It doesn't make sense to me to create my host path for this.

Answer (score 2):

this set the correct path and fixed the error:

```
  scrapytr:
    ...
    working_dir: /usr/src/app/project/api
    ...
```